# Pc powers on ok, but after mb update, power button blinks

Tags: boot, motherboard

So to start, everything is ok. 2) It is custom built desktop, built myself... I guy I know (at PC shop) told me to update motherboard software, after asking why after normal shutdown nothing on screen nor HDD led. Again everything is ok, but just curious, why the power button blinks slowly (every 1 second goes off then other second it will go back on) motherboard has only 1 led on (the indicator of power). Thanks if so.. Also after update keyboard doesn't work to enter UEFI either in this, only in windows. Luckily Asus has ai suite 3 what has a feature to click and restart to UEFI.

Comment: When you updated your mobo firmware it's possible the UEFI setting that enabled USB drivers before the OS loaded got turned off. Since you can get into UEFI via mouse I'd poke around for that setting so you can enable your keyboard. BTW this is why I keep a PS2 keyboard around :)

Comment: So for clarification, it sounds to me like the power LED blinks when the computer is turned off. Is that right?

Comment: yup, @JaredT only that, i am just curius

Comment: oh, and i have adapter too.. That is no problem, just wondering about the led blinking, "if PC hasn't exploded & is working fine everything is ok"

Comment: Yeah. I have no sources or anything to merit an official answer but in my experiences some motherboards have power-off idle lights. As long as no fans are spinning and nothing is warm to the touch you should be fine. Obviously there is power drain going on so if consumption is a concern just flip the switch on the power supply/unplug.